# Print date and timestamp in views-view-field--blog--block-1--image.html.twig

Tags: views, 8

How to print date and timestamp in views-view-field.html.twig ?

This is my html code

```
<span class="date"><span>27 <em>Mar</em></span></span>
```

And this is code for timestamp

```
<span class="timestamp">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        6 mins ago
</span>
```

To look like this. This is html look.

Date and timestamp need to be add in

views-view-field--blog--block-1--image.html.twig

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the template is for a date field and you want to display the date field in the format that you specified above.

Here is the article that might help http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

For PHP date formats you may refer to http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template

Comment: Date need to be add in views-view-field--blog--block-1--image.html.twig its view field for image not data field.